# terraform import azure vnet peering

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to import an existing azure vnet peering to a vhub (vwan hub).
The following is my code (without all the extra flags for paths etc):

```
terraform -a import 'module.solution.module.networking["dc_network"].azurerm_virtual_network.vnet' "/subscriptions/1111-1111-1111-1111-b0a0dba120be/resourceGroups/rgName/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnetName/virtualNetworkPeerings/RemoteVnetToHubPeering_11111222-d262-4671-8ff2-1112255"
```

I get the following error:

```
│ Error: parsing Resource ID "/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{rgNAme}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/{vnetName}/virtualNetworkPeerings/RemoteVnetToHubPeering_{UID}": ID contained more segments than required: "/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{rgNAme}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/{vnetName}/virtualNetworkPeerings/RemoteVnetToHubPeering_{UID}", map[virtualNetworkPeerings:RemoteVnetToHubPeering_{UID}]
```

which id is expected to import to import a vnet peering and am I using the right module or should I approach it from the virtual_wan side?

**UPDATE**
when trying the following: `import 'module.solution.azurerm_virtual_hub_connection.vhub_connection["vnet_to_hub"]' '/subscriptions/1111-1111-1111-1111-1111/resourceGroups/rg-global_wan/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualHubs/vhub-we/hubVirtualNetworkConnections/vnet_dc_TO_vhub_we'`

I get the following error:
[image]

And I am certain that the object exists.

Answer (score 0):

The command for import usually looks something like this:

```bash
terraform import azurerm_virtual_network_peering.example /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/mygroup1/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/network1/virtualNetworkPeerings/name_of_the_peering
```

Note that the resource is `azurerm_virtual_network_peering`, not `azurerm_virtual_network`.

Also, why do you include the UID of the peering in your command? That is not required and is probably why you're getting an error.

Comment: I am using rover with https://github.com/aztfmod/terraform-azurerm-caf. What would the .example be replaced with?

Comment: found it: module.solution.azurerm_virtual_hub_connection.vhub_connection["vnet_to_hub"]